# A question regarding functions/limits/the indeterminate form (0/0)

Tags: limits

> $$ g(x) = \frac{x^2 - cx + d}{x^2 - 4} \qquad\qquad  \lim_{x\to 2} g(x) = 3 $$ > Find c and d

I've tried plugging in 2 for x. But doing so yields the indeterminate form... Am I supposed to factor???

This question baffles me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the limit can exist is if the numerator goes to $0$, so decide that it will.

With that decision, you can use L'Hospital's rule to find the limit. Setting it equal to $3$ gives you an equation for $c$ that you can solve.

After you know $c$, calculate the $d$ that will make the numerator *actually* go to $0$ for $x\to 2$.

---

You can *also* start by factoring the denominator as $(x-2)(x+2)$. The $x-2$ factor needs to be there in the numerator too, and the other factor up here must be $x+k$ for some $k$, to get the right coefficient of $x^2$ in the product. Then you can find $k$ and multiply out $(x-2)(x+k)$ to find $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can factor or, better, do the division with remainder: the remainder of the division of $p(x)=x^2-cx+d$ by $x-2$ is $p(2)=4-2c+d$ and the quotient is easily seen to be $x+(2-c)$; thus the function can be written as
$$
\frac{(x+2-c)(x-2)+(4-2c+d)}{(x+2)(x-2)}=
\frac{x+2-c}{x+2}+\frac{4-2c+d}{(x+2)(x-2)}
$$
In order that the limit at $2$ exists finite, you need that $4-2c+d=0$.

Now you can plug in $2$ in the other term.

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x) = \frac{x^2 - cx + d}{x^2 - 4} \qquad\qquad  \lim_{x\to 2} g(x) = 3$$

You would want to start off by factoring the denominator.

$$g(x) = \frac{x^2 - cx + d}{x^2 - 4} \implies g(x) = \frac{x^2 - cx + d}{(x+2)(x-2)}$$

You need something in the numerator to cancel out the $(x-2)$ in the denominator.  A quadratic trinomial in the form $x^2+bx+c$ can be factored as $(x+b_1)(x+b_2)$, given that $b_1+b_2 = b$ and $b_1\cdot b_2 = c$. You can factor the numerator in this way.

$$g(x) = \frac{x^2 - cx + d}{(x+2)(x-2)} \implies g(x) = \frac{(x-c_1)(x-c_2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$$

Set one of $c_1$ or $c_2$ to be equal to $2$.

For $c_1 = 2$, you get:

$$g(x) = \frac{x-c_2}{x+2}$$

Add in the limit now.

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x-c_2}{x+2} = 3$$

$$\implies \frac{2-c_2}{4} = 3$$

Solve for $c_2$, then find $c$ by the fact that $c = c_1+c_2$ and $d$ by the fact that $d = c_1\cdot c_2$.